# How to use the range command to select a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a range that I need to select. The upper regions of the range is A2
which I can get using the following command -

```
Cells(2, 1)
```

The lower range, I can get using the following commands -

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

How can I combine all my cells command into something that range will select?

I tried

```
range=(cells(2,1)),(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row),(Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).select
```

but I get a format error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` returns an integer

and

`Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` returns an integer.

So you need `Cells(integer,integer)`.

As yours stands now it reads `range(A2),integer,integer.select`.

You don't use `select` and if you're going to use two integers, you need to wrap it in a cells(). And the whole thing in range().

```
 Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells((Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row), (Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)))
```

A better way to do this would be

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastcol As Integer
lastcol = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol))

End Sub
```

Now, you have no reason to `select` your range - just work with `rng` directly.

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for. it worked perfectly. and thanks for the tutorial, that helped too.

Comment: @DanM glad I could help. If your question is answered, click the green checkmark to mark the question as solved.